Splunk REST API not returning results for search query which has stats command in it
I am trying to use Splunk REST API to get my saved searches from splunk, create a search job with that query and then fetch the results for the returned SID. The problem I am experiencing is that whenever I fetch the results for the given SID it returns the response as:
 {
    "preview": false,
    "init_offset": 0,
    "post_process_count": 0,
    "messages": [],
    "results": []
}

which means there are no results for that query but when I search this query on Splunk's UI I get 820 events as results.
I tried using the adhoc_search_level=verbose in body of the request but it doesn't make any changes to the result. If I remove the stats keyword from the query it returns the results but whenever I try to use the stats command it returns an empty list of results. I also checked the job_manager of Splunk so when I made a post request to this URL https://localhost:8089/services/search/jobs?output_mode=json the job manager shows a job created which has 820 events in it with the same query I passed in the post request. But when I try to fetch the results with SID it returns 0 results.
Here is the search query:
search index="linux_sys" sourcetype="syslog" ("Failed password" OR "authentication failure")
| stats count by user, src_ip
| where count > 5
| sort - count


What does the request to fetch with the SID look like?

The problem got solved

Actually the Splunk REST API Documentation doesn't clarify that what are results and what are events. In the request if you fetch results for a query with no stats command it will respond with events but when you fetch the results for a query which has stats command it responds back with statistics tab results of splunk UI.

The solution which worked for me was to fetch the events instead of results and use the adhoc_search_level in post request when creating search job

You should post the relevant details (and maybe an example of the request to demonstrate) as an answer and then select it as the answer for your question.
